# Iterate through list with numbers (as text)

Tags: coordinates, list, iteration, select-by-expression

I want to iterate through a list of coordinates and see it the last coordinate matches the first coordinate. The coordinates are stored in have a GeoJSON string:

'''{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[76.863853437826,2.49314161017537,40.0],[-76.863723769784,2.4932265188545,0.3],[-76.8627395667136,2.49319550581276,0.0],[-76.863853431111,2.4931416101711111,0.0]]]},"properties":{"pointCount":"3","length":"0.0","area":"0.00001"}}]}'''

I first use findall method with regex to filter the coordinates from this string. This results in a list with this structure: listx = ['76.863853437826,2.49314161017537', '-76.863723769784,2.4932265188545', '-76.8627395667136,2.49319550581276', '-76.863853431111,2.4931416101711111']

Now, the 'strange' behaviour is that when I use this list in a for loop (for x in list) with an index, it only gives me the first number... Example:

```
for i in listx:
    first_coord = i[0]
    last_coord = i[-1]
    print(first_coord)
```

This results in '7' for the first coordinate. I would expect that it should plot the entire coordinate on index 0 (so: '76.863853437826,2.49314161017537').

I am a Phy-beginner, so probably I don't see something important here. Any solution how I can make sure that the entire coordinate string is being selected (first and last coordinate)?

Comment: Don't use regular expressions. Use json.

Comment: Do you mean you are a "Py-beginner"? I agree that you want to use `json.loads()` to convert the string to dictionaries/arrays which are trivially iterated. In the future you can pretty-priint the JSON so it's legible in a code block.

Comment: This is basically the same question, by the same user, as [Finding and replacing coordinates in GeoJSON](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401147/finding-and-replacing-coordinates-in-geojson).